# Variable "Name" is not readable, how can I fix it?

Tags: java, string

I was inserting some code to make a registration form, but iIfound this

```java
class User {

    private String Nama;
    private String Kelas;
    private int NIM;
    
    public String getNama{
        return Nama;
    }
    public String setNama{
        
    }
}
```

The error message was all *"variable is never read"*. Can someone explain why there is a message on this, and how I can fix it?

Comment: That's not an error, that's a warning.

Comment: Can you share the exact error message? which line does it refer to?

Comment: According to your code, your `setName` function is not correct.

Comment: If the exact message was "The value of the field ... is not used" then it is a warning because you never actually do anything with that variable so it currently is useless code.

Comment: As an aside, I'd strongly recommend starting to follow Java naming conventions, right from the start - fields normally start with lower case letters.

Comment: The code you shared will never compile.  Specifically the setNama method declares that it will return a String value but returns nothing.

Comment: Note that "variable is not readable" and "variable is never read" are *very, very* different error messages. Your code never uses the fields `Kelas` and `NIM`, so I'd expect you to get a warning or error about those fields.

Answer (score -1):

Though it is not clear where you use your codes, but the following is a java model class, with setter and getter method. Even it is not the direct answer of you question, but I have used this types of model class in my projects, one can find the idea of setter and getter from the following user class.

For using in various purposes You can create your `User` class as follows with constructors and setter and getter methods :

```
public class User {

    private String Nama;
    private String Kelas;
    private int NIM;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String nama, String kelas, int NIM) {
        Nama = nama;
        Kelas = kelas;
        this.NIM = NIM;
    }


    public String getNama() {
        return Nama;
    }

    public void setNama(String nama) {
        Nama = nama;
    }

    public String getKelas() {
        return Kelas;
    }

    public void setKelas(String kelas) {
        Kelas = kelas;
    }

    public int getNIM() {
        return NIM;
    }

    public void setNIM(int NIM) {
        this.NIM = NIM;
    }
}
```

Comment: That code wouldn't compile (and still violates Java naming conventions.)

Comment: this is a model class. I have used as this in my multiple projects. In this case,  So, I have to see where you use this.

Comment: Your class is called `User` but the constructors are for a class called `_A_Codes`. So no, I don't think you have used this code in multiple projects.

Comment: That's at least *better*, but you still haven't helped the questioner by explaining what's wrong with their existing code. (Hence the "Even it is not the direct answer of you question" in your answer - which shows this shouldn't be *presented* as an answer.)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to edit, Now Edited.